# How to use query for grid\enhancedGrid?

Tags: dojo, grid, store

I want to sort information in a dojo EnhancedGrid (connected to database through JsonRestStore). I know dojo grids provide functionality to sort based on a single column. However, in my grid, one column contains combined information from multiple fields (e.g., last name, first name, email, age) of database table. Is there a simple way to sort the grid or the data in the store based on a single filed in database table (e.g., last name)?

It seems I can use "query" to change the view of the store (grid is a view of the store if I understand correctly), but I don't understand how to write a query to do that.  Can anyone give me more information about the syntax of using query or how to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use what is called a comparatorMap for customized grid sorting.

here's one example :
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-dojogrid/index.html
(look for the section 'Listing 15. Customize the sort function of Dojo
Grid')

inside the comparator map function is where you would convert the strings to
numbers and make the numeric comparison.

Comment: I don't need converting strings to numbers though

Comment: converting the string to numbers is what happens inside the comparator map, you dont have to worry about its working, just see the sample in the given link, thats the way to do a custom sorting in a dojo grid. The values shown in the grid will not be changed using this.